# How much is the visa cost for South Korea from India?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea

I have been invited to an business event in Seoul, South Korea. I'm an Indian citizen. What is the cost for such visas?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you contacted e.g. the South Korean Embassy in India, if there is one?

Comment: No I have not contacted. I will visit delhi in few days. Before going I was searching online.

Comment: Why this post is being given negative votes? Its a valid question.

Comment: A downvote can mean e.g. "this question does not show any research effort". Hence my downvote and comment.

Comment: Asking on stackexchange is also parts of research.

Comment: Hint: type "south korean embassy india" in google. Click on the embassy link. In "Consular/Visa service" click "For Indian Applicants". Document #27 in the list has title "Change of Visa Fees w.e.f. 1st July, 2016". You'll find your information there. Next time please at least open Google before asking your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Consulate General of the Republic of Korea](http://ind-chennai.mofa.go.kr/webmodule/htsboard/template/read/legengreadboard.jsp?typeID=16&boardid=14780&seqno=736150&c=&t=&pagenum=1&tableName=TYPE_ENGLEGATIO&pc=&dc=&wc=&lu=&vu=&iu=&du=) the prices are the following:

```
| Visa Type                                | General   | Express   |
|------------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|
| Short Term, Single Entry (below 90days)  | Rs. 2,640 | Rs. 4,620 |
| Long Term, Single Entry (over 90days)    | Rs. 3,960 | Rs. 5,940 |
| Double Entry                             | Rs. 4,620 | Rs. 7,260 |
| (each visit, Max 30days during 6 months) |           |           |
| Multiple Entry                           | Rs. 5,940 | Rs. 8,580 |
| (each visit, Max 90 days during 1 year)  |           |           |
```